# How to validate input fields in adaptive card bot framework v4 (waterfall model) c#

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an adaptive card which include the input fields

1. Name
2. Phone Number
3. Email
4. Address

I want to validate the fields - validation as below

1. Name - should not empty and min char 5 , max char 20
2. Phone Number - should not empty and only 10 digit
3. Email - should not empty and all character and format should be xxxx@wert.com
4. Address - should not empty.

how to validate input field from adaptive card in bot framework v4 in c# ?
can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please include your code snippet as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to do validation for an Adaptive Card. The best option would be to use [ActivityPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/ActivityPrompt.cs) with a custom validator.

Basically:

1. Create an Adaptive Card
2. Create an ActivityPrompt
3. Add the Adaptive Card to the `Attachments` property of your ActivityPrompt
4. Send the prompt with a custom validator
5. In the validator, do all of your custom validation.

The reason you need to use ActivityPrompt is because AdaptiveCard input comes back in `Activity.Value` instead of `Activity.Text` and ActivityPrompt will let you call validation on the whole activity.

Alternatively, you may find [ActivityCardPrompt](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Prompts#adaptive-card-prompt) helpful, but you'll still need to use your own validator.